# Time complexity of creation of BST

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

As in case of binary heap creation of n node, its time complexity turns out to be O(n) not nlog(n) considering fact that at any height h there will be atmax

[image]

nodes with will require atmost O(h) time to heapify.

[image]

On the similar lines, i wanted to prove creation of BST. For that i use the fact that at any depth d there can be atmost 2^d nodes which will take atmax O(d) time for insertion. So Equation would be

[image]

How come this equation leads to nlog(n)-expected time complexity of BST creation or O(n^2)-worst case complexity. Please suggest a way how to proceed further from above equation.

Comment: Your math is incorrect. Your sums come out wrong, because most of the nodes are inserted at the greater depths.  Creation of a binary heap is O(N) because a bottom-up construction is used instead of inserting and then heapifying every element.  If you had to insert each one independently, it would be O(N log N).

Comment: What is wrong here please specify, For n-node bst atleast floor(log(n)) -height is required, at each depth d it will have 2^d node, considering a balanced bst of 15 node height with come out to be floor(log(15)) ie 3 and at level-3 it will have 2^3 nodes ie 8 nodes. and for insertion scenario all 8 nodes will have to travel down to its last level thus producing 2^d*h kind of equation. If it is wrong what i am missing here?

Comment: h, d, and n are related.  It's easier to do it this way:  HALF the nodes will be inserted at depth log(n), so if insertion takes time proportional to depth, then total insertion time is >= O(0.5 n log n) >= O(n log n).  Similarly, ALL nodes will be inserted at depth <= log(n), so total time is <= O(n log n)

Comment: I know if i think this way it will be easy to visualise the complexity as nlog(n) but the expansion of above equation looks something that it should be more than nlog(n). That's why i asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved that series.

let T=log(N)   ie 2^T = N(no of nodes)............(1)
problem becomes Summation_of(2^d * d) where d ranges from o to T. so

```
    G(T)        = 0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 2*2^2 + ..... + T*2^T.

    2G(T)       =         0*2^1 + 1*2^2 + ..... +(T-1)*2^T + T*2^(T+1) 

    2G(T)-G(T)  = 0     - 2^1    -2^2   - ..... - 2^T + 2T*2^T
 
    G(T)        =       - 2^(T+1)-2  + 2T*2^T
    G(T)        =   2( (T-1)2^T  +1 )
    which is        =   2( (log(N)-1)N +1 )...........from (1)
```

Thus gives upper bound as N log (N) (considering balanced trees)